# Absolutely positioned div is too wide when padding: %

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one `position:static` and one `position:absolute`. Despite having the same width and padding values, the absolutely positioned div gets about 17px wider. This only happens when I specify the horizontal padding as a percentage. How do I get these divs to be the same width without removing the % padding?

```css
.foo { 
  border:2px solid blue; 
  background: pink; 
  width: 200px; 
  padding: 20px 20%; 
}

.foo:nth-child(3) { 
  border-color: red; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:96px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I would like to think that you would have a normalize `css` snippet in your base file. https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 3):

I know how to fix this:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I'm just not 100% sure why this is happening. It probably has something to do with the absolute positioned element does not share the same containing element (body vs html) and that is what padding that uses percentages is based off of.

Comment: Yeah. You can also see a similar effect by doing `body { margin: 0 }`. The browser default is `body { margin: 8 }`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is in reality a pretty common one: default margin on the body.

By adding `margin: 0;` for the `body`, the issue is solved. The reason why `padding: 20px 20%;` behaves differently for the elements is because the percentage value is based on the width of the parent - for the statically positioned elements, this is reduced by the default margin. However, for the absolutely positioned element, this margin on the body is ignored (`html` rather than `body` is treated as its parent, which has no margin) and the 20% will be of a larger number.

This is also why you had to use `top:96px;` instead of `top:88px` (40px in padding + 8px in borders) for that absolutely-positioned element - the default margin pushed down the top two elements.

Here's your code, adjusted accordingly:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.foo {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px 20%;
}
.foo:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because percentages are resolved relatively to the [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details), which varies in the absolute case.

For the in-flow elements, the containing block is established by the `body` element, which by default has some margin, so it's narrower than the viewport.

For the absolutely positioned element, the containing block is established by the nearest positioned ancestor. Since there isn't any, it's the [initial containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#x1), established by the viewport.

The solution is positioning `body` so that it establish the containing block for the absolutely positioned element:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative; /* Establish the containing block for absolutely positioned descendants */
}
.foo {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px 20%;
}
.foo:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but it shows up in the top spot in google for certain terms, so I thought I'd go ahead and give the correct answer.

Yes, this does have to do with inheriting parent, but not in the way described. Body inherits it's values from the html tag, meaning that the issue isn't with the body tag.

The clue is in the very specific 17 pixels. That is the default width of the scrollbar in chrome.

Looking at the code here, the width was specified in %. Setting the body to

```
width:100%
margin:0px
padding:0px
```

will set the body to be the same width as the  tag

The  tag in turn will be 100% of the AVAILABLE window, which means that if your content generates a scrollbar, that width is now -17 pixels wide.

The sollution is to set either your body or your html tag (yes, you can style that one too) to

```
width:100vw;
```

vw doesn't take the scrollbar into account, but instead only displays the windows width.

I hope that makes sense, and that I have managed to help you solve your problem.